# debugging information not find in vc++ dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-c++, dll

I have a dll and I want to debug my dll.I have also browse the path of exe.But now I want to change the path of that exe because it was not correct exe.In the property I have remove the path of exe from the debugging option also.but when I start the debugging the error message show that
 **Debugging information for exe cannot be found or does not match.Binary was not build with debug information**
And output window show that..............

```
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\dll_example\hello.exe', Binary was not built with debug information.
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinSCard.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\dll_example\helloworld.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\msvcr90.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oledlg.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\olepro32.dll'
'hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'
The program '[0x1740] hello.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the "Binary was not built with debug information." it seems that your binary was build in "Release" configuration. You have at least two options here:

i) build the binary in the "Debug" configuration

ii) change the project settings so that a Program Database file (PDB) is generated in the release configuration (check for example [this](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/08/31/correctly-creating-native-c-release-build-pdbs.aspx)). The PDB file should reside in the same directory as your EXE and with it you should be able also to debug your application.

Comment: actually I have exe which is in VC++ 6 and It is restricted to change the version of the exe.and the dll is now in vs2008 and pdb file of the dll is also in the same folder in which dll reside.one important thing pdb of exe in vc++ 6 version.So I think it will not be compatible with present senarios.